# How to load JasperReports font extensions into Spring based application?

Tags: java, spring, jasper-reports

I'm trying to load JasperReports font extension to my project.
I have jasperreports-fonts-6.0.0 on classpath (Maven) that contains variations of DejaVu fonts.

But when I try to set pdf font name by properties:

```
final JRPropertiesUtil jrProps = JRPropertiesUtil.getInstance(DefaultJasperReportsContext.getInstance());

jrProps.setProperty(JRFont.DEFAULT_PDF_FONT_NAME, "DejaVu Sans");
jrProps.setProperty(JRFont.DEFAULT_PDF_ENCODING, "Identity-H");
jrProps.setProperty(JRFont.DEFAULT_PDF_EMBEDDED, "TRUE");
```

I keep getting error:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: Could not load the following font: 
pdfFontName: DejaVu Sans
pdfEncoding: Identity-H
isPdfEmbedded : true
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.getFont(JRPdfExporter.java:2323)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.writePageAnchor(JRPdfExporter.java:985)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportReportToStream(JRPdfExporter.java:915)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportReport(JRPdfExporter.java:537)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperExportManager.exportToPdfStream(JasperExportManager.java:196)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(JasperExportManager.java:533)
```

But, when setting full path to the font in jar, everything works fine.

```
jrProps.setProperty(JRFont.DEFAULT_PDF_FONT_NAME, "net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSerif.ttf");
```

Is there need to take additional action to include this font extension to Spring application?

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

**Solution:**

Problem was wrong font parameter key.

Changed

`jrProps.setProperty(JRFont.DEFAULT_PDF_FONT_NAME, "DejaVu Sans");`

to

`jrProps.setProperty(JRFont.DEFAULT_FONT_NAME, "DejaVu Sans");`

Comment: Did You tried put settings in `jasperreports.properties` file (file in classpath, in maven project `src/main/resources`) ?
`net.sf.jasperreports.default.font.name=DejaVu Serif
net.sf.jasperreports.default.pdf.encoding=Identity-H
net.sf.jasperreports.default.pdf.embedded=TRUE`

Comment: Yes, tried that, but no luck.  
  
Inside jasperreports-fonts-6.0.0.jar there is file called    `jasperreports_extension.properties` that contains:  
`net.sf.jasperreports.extension.registry.factory.simple.font.families=net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontExtensionsRegistryFactory
net.sf.jasperreports.extension.simple.font.families.dejavu=net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/fonts.xml`  
  
  I tried change font factory to:
`net.sf.jasperreports.extension.registry.factory.fonts=net.sf.jasperreports.extensions.SpringExtensionsRegistryFactory`  
  
But without success (same error).

Comment: Did you try to load ***SansSerif*** font without setting the `DEFAULT_PDF_ENCODING` & `DEFAULT_PDF_EMBEDDED` properties, for example?

Comment: Does it work in simple Java application (not in Spring context)?

Comment: I don't know what is wrong with Your app yet ;), but I've created simple Spring4 servlet that provide pdf with use of `jasperreports.properties` and works good. You can look at [here](https://github.com/marioosh-net/spring-jasper).

Comment: Thank you! Following your example I found a problem.
Problem was wrong font parameter key. I used `net.sf.jasperreports.default.pdf.font.name` instead of `net.sf.jasperreports.default.font.name`.
After replace that, everything works like charm.

Thank you very much, Sir! :)